# Shopping cart - preventing back button

Tags: user-interface, shopping-cart, back

I have a site with a shopping cart system, the issue is that we are having some members hit the remove item button, which updates the line item with a "removed" flag - then hitting the browser back button, which then shows the cart in the previous state - with the line item intact.

If they pay in this state we are getting all sorts of issues when the sales is processed as one of more of the items that they pay for don't get processed. which means we manually have to pick up the pieces at a later date.

Is there any standard way to handle this situation - ie I know we can provide an "undo" button - but the user is not always going to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to detail the solution that I am ending up with, in case other people have a similar issue.

Our payment gateway provides a way to pass custom information on to our payment process system, we are planning to pass along the id's of all items that are in the cart, and when we get them back we will use this to un-remove the removed items.

This works using the same process that is causing the issue in the first place, as the cart page does not reload on a browser back.

This is assuming that by pressing the back is the user trying to undo his action, as the payment value is confirmed prior to the sale we can be reasonably sure that the cart is how the user wanted it if its is pushed though.

we are also providing a undo system as well as having the javascript back protection in order to prevent it from being needed, 10 solutions are better than one in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use filter for this situation. And ya... You can also prevent user to go back by disabling back button using simple java script.

http://www.viralpatel.net

visit this one.
This will become helpful for you.

Comment: The issue with javascript is that you cannot rely on it.